# Set value of a column to NA based on conditions in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame, a reproducible example is as follows:

```
structure(list(subscriberid = c(1177460837L, 1177460837L, 1177460837L, 
1146526049L, 1146526049L, 1146526049L), variable = c("3134", 
"4550", "4550", "5160", "2530", "2530"), value = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 
2, 2), gender = c(2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2), cwe = c(NA, 50L, 50L, NA, 
30L, 30L), hw = c(NA, 48L, 48L, NA, 26L, 26L), resp = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), cna = c(3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("subscriberid", 
"variable", "value", "gender", "cwe", "hw", "resp", "cna"), row.names = c(4L, 
5L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 11L), class = "data.frame")
```

The actual data frame looks like this:

```
   subscriberid variable value gender cwe hw resp cna
4    1177460837     3134     1      2  NA NA   NA   3
5    1177460837     4550     2      2  50 48   NA   1
6    1177460837     4550     2      2  50 48   NA   1
9    1146526049     5160     1      1  NA NA   NA   3
10   1146526049     2530     2      2  30 26   NA   1
11   1146526049     2530     2      2  30 26   NA   1
```

In the above df, row 5 and 6 are exactly the same.  From row 5, I want to remove 48 and row 6 I want to remove 50.  Essentially, I want to retain only one age in a row and set the other to NA. I tried using a for loop but that sets column values in the column that I refer in both the rows to NA.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(test)) {
  test$hw[i] <- ifelse(!is.na(test$cwe[i]) & !is.na(test$hw[i]), NA, test$hw[i])
}
```

I am trying to set an if condition to identify if both the rows are same, then I want to iteratively remove one of the values from the first row and remove the other from the second.

The desired output is as follows:

```
  subscriberid variable value gender cwe hw resp cna
4    1177460837     3134     1      2  NA NA   NA   3
5    1177460837     4550     2      2  50 NA   NA   1
6    1177460837     4550     2      2  NA 48   NA   1
9    1146526049     5160     1      1  NA NA   NA   3
10   1146526049     2530     2      2  30 NA   NA   1
11   1146526049     2530     2      2  NA 26   NA   1
```

Comment: Identical rows must be consecutive ? And there can only be two identical rows ?

Comment: @digEmAll  Yes...identical rows are always consecutive and very rarely I get 3 identical rows.  But since they are sporadic, I am removing them from the df

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution :

```
# create a logical vector indicating if current row is identical to previous one
# N.B.: do.call("paste",c(DF,sep="\r")) is used internally by "duplicated.data.frame" function
rowStrings <- do.call("paste", c(DF, sep = "\r"))
currRowIsEqualToPrev <- rowStrings[-1] == rowStrings[-length(rowStrings)]

# set first row hw = NA and second identical row cwe = NA
DF[c(FALSE,currRowIsEqualToPrev),'hw'] <- NA
DF[c(currRowIsEqualToPrev,FALSE),'cwe'] <- NA

> DF
   subscriberid variable value gender cwe hw resp cna
4    1177460837     3134     1      2  NA NA   NA   3
5    1177460837     4550     2      2  NA 48   NA   1
6    1177460837     4550     2      2  50 NA   NA   1
9    1146526049     5160     1      1  NA NA   NA   3
10   1146526049     2530     2      2  NA 26   NA   1
11   1146526049     2530     2      2  30 NA   NA   1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of `which()` and `duplicated()` to receive duplicated rows.
Because you need to change values twice of the rows, you have to create a copy of the dataframe. Note that this will only work if the identical rows are always consecutive.

```
dfNA <- df
dfNA$hw[which(duplicated(df))-1] <- NA
dfNA$cwe[which(duplicated(df))] <- NA

dfNA
#   subscriberid variable value gender cwe hw resp cna
#4    1177460837     3134     1      2  NA NA   NA   3
#5    1177460837     4550     2      2  50 NA   NA   1
#6    1177460837     4550     2      2  NA 48   NA   1
#9    1146526049     5160     1      1  NA NA   NA   3
#10   1146526049     2530     2      2  30 NA   NA   1
#11   1146526049     2530     2      2  NA 26   NA   1
```

Comment: Good approach, the only problem would raise in case of non-consecutive duplicated rows, but it should not happen according to the OP

Comment: That is true, but the OP mentions that the identical rows are always consecutive. The problem arises as well when there is 3 or more identical rows. But he is planning to remove those.

Answer (score 2):

Using *lead* and *lag* from *dplyr* package:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(subscriberid, variable) %>% 
  mutate(cwe = if_else(lead(cwe) == cwe, cwe, NA_integer_),
         hw = if_else(lag(hw) == hw, hw, NA_integer_)) %>% 
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 6 x 8
#   subscriberid variable value gender   cwe    hw resp    cna
#          <int>    <int> <int>  <int> <int> <int> <lgl> <int>
# 1   1177460837     3134     1      2    NA    NA NA        3
# 2   1177460837     4550     2      2    50    NA NA        1
# 3   1177460837     4550     2      2    NA    48 NA        1
# 4   1146526049     5160     1      1    NA    NA NA        3
# 5   1146526049     2530     2      2    30    NA NA        1
# 6   1146526049     2530     2      2    NA    26 NA        1
```

Answer (score 1):

I took a shot at it. This relies on using `group_by` from `dplyr` to find duplicate rows. This method assumes that rows can be reliably be identified as identical by using the `subscriberid`, `variable`, `value`, `gender`, `resp`, and `cna` columns alone.

Because it is operating within groups only, it will work even if a preceding non-identical row contains the same value for `cwe` (I did check this, but I would also confirm it for yourself if I were you).

```
library(dplyr)

ndf <- df %>%
       group_by(subscriberid, variable, value, gender, resp, cna) %>%
       mutate(cwe = na_if(cwe, lag(cwe)),
              hw = na_if(hw, lead(hw))) %>%
       ungroup()
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 8
  subscriberid variable value gender   cwe    hw  resp   cna
         <int> <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1   1177460837 3134        1.     2.    NA    NA    NA     3
2   1177460837 4550        2.     2.    50    NA    NA     1
3   1177460837 4550        2.     2.    NA    48    NA     1
4   1146526049 5160        1.     1.    NA    NA    NA     3
5   1146526049 2530        2.     2.    30    NA    NA     1
6   1146526049 2530        2.     2.    NA    26    NA     1
```